# Android XML Is there a way to use the tool namespace with custom attributes?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml, android-tools-namespace

I've created a custom view with attributes. Is there a way to use those attributes with android tools in Android studio?

for example :

```
<MyOwnCoolView
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:padding="3dp"
    tools:dividerAngle="2"/>
```

Where the attr file is :

```
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="MyOwnCoolView">
    <attr name="dividerAngle" format="float"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: Why would you use the tool namespace? You can use the "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" namespace.

Comment: to have a place holder with value. to see how it all looks in the design view.  later during run-time this view will get various values.

Comment: As far as I know the design preview should work with "schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" too, be sure to retrieve the values in the class constructor.

Comment: Of course it works, but the dummy value stays there also for the release. Using tool you don't have to worry about "cleaning" the dummy data

Comment: Ok I got it finally :) you should edit your question to make this clear. What happens if you set tools:dividerAngle ? Nothing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My opinion is that you can't.

There's an official, though *very* old, page [here](http://tools.android.com/tips/layout-designtime-attributes) that quotes:

> Designtime attributes can only be used for framework resources, not
>   custom attributes at this point.

Comment: You could try filing a feature request on the support site.

Comment: @RCB, do you know if this is still the case?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing for a while now. Decided to make a library that allows one to do it. https://github.com/giljulio/sneakpeek

Answer (score 1):

I've written a tiny library that allows you define design-time attributes for your views: https://github.com/paulmanta/app-tools-attrs

Firstly, you have to declare separate attributes that you want to as at design-time:

```
<declare-styleable name="MyWidget">
    <attr name="title" format="string"/>
    <attr name="tools_title" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Finally, when you initialize your custom view use the `AppToolsAttrs` class instead of accessing attributes directly from a `TypedArray`:

```
AppToolsAttrs.getString(a, isInEditMode(), R.styleable.MyWidget_title, R.styleable.MyWidget_tools_title)
```

You can then use your design-time attributes like this:

```
<com.myapplication.MyWidget
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tools_title="Lorem ipsum"
    app:title="@string/real_title"/>
```

[Gil already posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45501007/627005) with a different library that allows you do this. His implementation is really smart and it allows you to use the actual `tools:` namespace without having to duplicate attributes. Unfortunately, it's incompatible with Android Studio's auto-complete feature.