# Previewing horizontal recyclerview in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I found out how to preview a list item by using

```
tools:listitem="@layout/my_item_layout"
```

Android studio however is previewing the recyclerview as a vertical list. Is there a way to tell Android Studio to display the layout preview in a horizontal fashion using `LinearLayoutManager`?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Add a LayoutManager and set a horizontal orientation.

Here an example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/homesRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />
```

Comment: you can also add them using the tools namespace (i.e. `tools:orientation` and `tools:layoutManager`) and then it only impacts the IDE preview and you can continue setting those values in code.

Comment: Replace `app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"` with `app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"` when using AndroidX libraries :)

Answer (score 29):

If you are using androidx libraries:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/homesRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />
```

Comment: This converted by RecyclerView to horizontal but `tools:listitem` did not work for me with `androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha01`.  I could only see the horizontal list in design mode if I didn't use `tools:listitem`

Comment: I figured out it was my fault because my list item layout specified `android:layout_width="match_parent"`.  By changing it to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` I can no scroll horizontally in Android Studio's design tab using `androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha01`.

Answer (score 13):

Just use in your layout the **`app:layoutManager`** and the **`android:orientation`** attributes and add them also using the **`tools`** namespace.
Something like:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/ly_item"
    tools:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:orientation="horizontal"
    ../>
```

Comment: This should be the top answer.

"tools" effects only the preview.

"app:" actually wires your RV to a layout manager, which might not be the preferred behavior

Comment: hi gabriele could help me out here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76786965/facing-issue-while-validating-amongst-the-edittexts-in-recyclerview

Answer (score 7):

the accepted answer works accurately. For androidx just use this in your recyclerView

`app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
 android:orientation="horizontal"`

Answer (score 0):

AndroidX

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    tools:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item"
    tools:orientation="horizontal"/>
```

[[Read more here]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49320755/4770877)

Answer (score 0):

To show the preview of the `RecyclerView` in Android, follow these steps:

- Add this line in the parent layout widget:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

- Now add a property in the RecyclerView:

```
app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

**Example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerQueueItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:itemCount="10"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_queue_token_number" 
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

for new recyclerView version, add this line in your code.

```
app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
tools:listitem="@layout/item_date"
```

don't forget to add this too

```
tools:orientation="horizontal"
```

and then the horizontal recyclerView would show in preview

check below picture

[image]

Answer (score -6):

Otherwise you can use in java file :

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
```

Comment: question is to see in preview in android studio not actual implementation.